# Validating statistical tests for value at risk and expected shortfall

Tags: validation, quantiles, conditional-expectation, finance

I am trying to figure out if value-at-risk (VaR, a quantile) type tests could capture if expected shortfall (expectations above a quantile) point forecast generated from a type of model could be regarded as accurate or not.

I base my curiosity from this quote from [a document by the Basel Committee](http://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs_wp19.pdf):

> Whether specialised ES backtests are good or not, one simple option is always available: during an ES calculation, the VaR at the same can be generated as a by-product with low additional effort. One can backtest this VaR with traditional methods; if the VaR is rejected, the corresponding ES calculation can hardly be correct.

Since it is possible to define expected shortfall as the average of all the value-at-risk estimates exceeding a risk level, this logic could be extended as to saying: if it is likely that the expected shortfall is correct, then we could validate some value-at-risk estimates included in expected shortfall; if they are accepted, then we have increased confidence in the expected shortfall estimate. Assume I have such a test called X.

My question is now, if I wanted to test the quality of my test from my knowledge, it is possible to use Monte Carlo simulations to determine the power of X, but are there any statistical tools/procedures that could tell me if X could tell me anything about expected shortfall?

Comment: Cool question; welcome to CV!

Comment: I think the general point in Basel is one of model risk rather than one of estimating confidence intervals on risk statistics. I'd focus first on estimating the right models for your data. Anyway, you can try a bootstrapping approach. Alternately you could look into the approach in this paper: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1971808

Comment: Thank you John. You see, now that Basel has proposed to switch from VaR to ES in their next accord there is a strong need for a way for validation, both internally and externally. Such methods used in the past have not been adequate as it has recently been noted that ES is not elicitable, so it can't be tested directly http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1645. However, VaR is possible to backtest and some academics suggests to backtest a battery of VaRs in the tail area (beyond the risk level of ES) to test the potential of the model to produce adequate ES estimates (see prior link).